# Issue with assertion in webdriver and TestNG

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am facing a wired situation while doing an assertion.
I am asserting the value inside each list (Lists are supposed to contain same value even though that are not List of same objects)

Here is my assertion code :

```
for (int i=0 ; i< rst.size(); i++)

         {
             Assert.assertSame(l.get(i).getName(),rst.get(i).getText());
```

Here is the response I am getting :

```
FAILED: srch("tsk", "http://frstmwarwebsrv2.orsyptst.com:9000/duobject?   searchString=TSK&filtercheck=nameSWF&p.index=0&p.size=8")
java.lang.AssertionError: expected [TSK(ACE700J)(000)(ACE700JU00)(000)] but found    [TSK(ACE700J)(000)(ACE700JU00)(000)]
         }
```

I have changed the above as advised by I am still getting the same error :

```
Assert.assertSame ((l.get(i).getName().trim()),  rst.get(i).getText().trim());
```

Comment: Trim the strings first. I suspect it may be a whitespace issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do I need to convert each cell's value to String before trimming? is there any other way of doing it without converting to String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods `getName()` and `getText()` both return Strings, so (assuming your problem is only leading and trailing white space) all you need to do is add `.trim()`, like so:

```
Assert.assertEquals(l.get(i).getName().trim(),rst.get(i).getText().trim());
```

It seems, also, that what you want to do is test that different objects in memory are *meaningfully equal*.  This means you want to use `assertEquals()`, not `assertSame()`.

- **assertEquals()** asserts that two objects, which may or may not be different objects in memory, are meaningfully equal (or, as you put it, have the same value).
- **assertSame()** asserts that two objects are in fact the same object in memory -- so if you run assertSame() on two objects with "the same value" but which are not the same object in memory, your test will fail.

Comment: This worked but only with assertEquals, not sure what is the difference between assertEquals and assertSame

Comment: I see.  This means that your objects must be different object in memory.  I'll modify my answer to account for this.

Comment: Yes indeed the two Strings are the same but objects are different, thanks.